# Read object from file in java

Tags: java

I have a Class which has a method to generate id incrementally
I created some objects and add to a vector ,then save to a .dat file 
 then I read the file and add objects to the vector 
But, when I open the program again to create another objects, it starts from the initial id, it doesn't continue from the last id. 
What is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: You need a database to read and write properly. If this is a dummy program you can you use a  .txt or a .json file where you can read and write from. You can also use this method: 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

Comment: Save them how? Do you read them ever? If so, how? Did you have some actual code you were asking about, or is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: the class has a method to in generate id incrementally
I created some object and add to a vector , save to file
then I read the file and add objects to vector
the thing I want is when I create new object , its id is continue incrementally  from the last id

Comment: You have not answered a single one of my three questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a counter-like id generator and the starting id being initialized during startup. Two ways:

1. store the last index used in a file that you load first to retrieve it and continue your sequence
2. using such IDs is generally not considered as good, if you want UUID (Universally Unique IDs) java provides you a class for such `java.util.UUID`.